# Power Automate convert to PDF

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, converters, power-automate

I have a basic flow to save email attachments to a SharePoint folder, but I would like to extend this to also convert attachments in any format (XLSX,TXT,DOCX etc.) to PDFs. Illustration below.

Most of the Power Automate options for SharePoint like Get Item retrieve from a list or a specific file, not from a library. [Encodian](https://support.encodian.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360011123574-Convert-to-PDF) and [Adobe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/adobepdftools/#convert-document-to-pdf) have actions to do this. But is there a license-free way to convert for SharePoint files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is possible to convert all types of files to PDF files.

However, you can use **OneDrive for Business** connector for converting files from SharePoint/OneDrive to PDF files.

Check this flow template for this: [Convert a file to PDF using OneDrive for Business](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-US/templates/details/0ffc6d1b79ea481bbbc820df7273f303/convert-a-file-to-pdf-using-onedrive-for-business/)

So, you can save email attachments to SharePoint/OneDrive and convert those using above connector.

Also check below examples for similar requirements:

1. [Convert Office documents to PDF on the fly using Microsoft Flow](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/tr-tr/blog/convert-pdf-with-microsoft-flow-nov-2018/)
2. [Power Automate – Convert Word document to PDF](https://spknowledge.com/2020/09/26/power-automate-convert-word-document-to-pdf/)